How to use unpkg-server
I'm trying to use unpkg-server along with verdaccio to have a private registry for my company packages.
The thing is that i have been searching for a solution like unpkg and the closest I could found is unpkg-server. But there isn't much information about this. I already tryed it in local but can't figure out the url i have to go in order to get the package files like unpkg.
Anyone know how this works?
